# Reorder dynamic table in html using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a html page where i add rows and delete rows dynamically. Now my goal is to reorder the rows which updated id.

for example i have 3 column in a row in which the 3rd column is given a id based on the rowid. so once i delete a row , i need to reorder this id. is this possible using javascript.

Sample code is here

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
      function addRow(tableID) {

           var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

           var rowCount = table.rows.length;
           var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

           var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
           var element1 = document.createElement("input");
           element1.type = "checkbox";
           cell1.appendChild(element1);

           var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
           cell2.innerHTML = rowCount ;

           var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
           var element2 = document.createElement("input");
           element2.type = "text";
           element2.id = "batch"+rowCount;
           cell3.appendChild(element2);

      }

      function deleteRow(tableID) {
           try {
           var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
           var rowCount = table.rows.length;

           for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                     table.deleteRow(i);
                     rowCount--;
                     i--;
                }

           }
           }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
           }
      }

 </SCRIPT>
```

```
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
      <TR>
      </TR>
 </TABLE>
```

Comment: you mean you want to reorder all <tr> id's?

Comment: yes. I need to update the id s of the text as well.

Regards,
Manish Jain

Comment: in fact you should start your for structure from 1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function reorder(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=1; i<=rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        row.cells[1].innerHTML= i;
    }
}
```

Hope it work.

Comment: Hi Poya, I have got the code to reorder the table. I would try the code given by you and get back to you with the results. Thanks a lot for taking out time and replying to the queries.